# how do I post data to CKRecord Fields objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value, cloudkit

I am trying to fetch my CloudKit record and then update it with new data.
I have imported CloudKit framework
I have added CloudKit and key/values to my capabilities.
I have put them into my entitlements.
I have use Schemas to create new custom type private records and added 5 fields.
I would like to know how to update these field strings in my iphone app and then get that information on my watch app and put the data in text labels.
I have tried various things but nothing seems to be working.
I am working in objc.
Could someone help me.

Here is some code I am trying to get to work but with little success.
As a 68 yr old retired art teacher teaching myself this I am not a trained coder and need all the help I can get.

**I just tried this and it runs through, but I can't see where I put in the values for the keys I have put in.  Where do I put those values to modify.**

```
[[CKContainer defaultContainer].privateCloudDatabase fetchRecordWithID:recordID
                         completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error) {
            record = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType: @"MyPoolInfo"];
            [record setObject: self.myTemp forKey: @"temperature"];
            [record setObject: self.myDate forKey: @"date"];
            [record setObject: self.myLevel forKey: @"level"];
            [record setObject: self.myTrip forKey: @"trip"];
            [record setObject: self.myBattery forKey: @"battery"];
            NSArray *myFields = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:record,nil];
            //NSArray *recordsToSave = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.myTemp,self.myDate,self.myLevel,self.myTrip,self.myBattery, nil];
            CKModifyRecordsOperation *modifyRecords= [[CKModifyRecordsOperation alloc]
                             initWithRecordsToSave:myFields recordIDsToDelete:nil];
          //[modifyRecords setValue:@"one" forKey:@"temperature"];
                      modifyRecords.savePolicy=CKRecordSaveAllKeys;
                      modifyRecords.qualityOfService=NSQualityOfServiceUserInitiated;
                      modifyRecords.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock=
                           ^(NSArray * savedRecords, NSArray * deletedRecordIDs, NSError * operationError){
            //   the completion block code here
                               
                               NSLog(@"savedRecords:%@",savedRecords);
                        };
                      
            
            [[CKContainer defaultContainer].privateCloudDatabase addOperation:modifyRecords];
         }];
```

I have also tried this

```
CKRecord *record = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType: @"Pools"];
            [record setObject: self.myTemp forKey: @"temperature"];
            [record setObject: self.myDate forKey: @"date"];
            [record setObject: self.myLevel forKey: @"level"];
            [record setObject: self.myTrip forKey: @"trip"];
            [record setObject: self.myBattery forKey: @"battery"];
            [[CKContainer defaultContainer].privateCloudDatabase saveRecord:record completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error)
              { if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"this is being accessed1");
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"this is bad");
            }
              }];
```

**I put in an error if and it says there is an error in what I'm doing**

Comment: Your record ID is probably invalid.  Where does `recordID` on the second line come from?

Comment: On my CloudKit Dashboard I created a private database with custom type record Pool and gave it a name of "MyPoolInfo".  This is where the Name comes from.  I have tried added a line of code at the end of the second batch to actually save the data but it doesn't show up in my dashboard under query.

Comment: I have changed some of my first code and I actually runs through without error but doesn't save anything.  I don't see in the code where it sets what values are supposed to be saved for the different field keys.

Comment: this is what my log says.  I'm not sure how to see what is the actual problem.   ```2021-01-20 06:46:05.856774-0700 iphoneMQTT[18400:962147] this is bad
2021-01-20 06:46:05.939680-0700 iphoneMQTT[18400:962149] savedRecords:(
)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use CKRecord objects to pass data in and out of the database. Each one must have a record type matching the records you defined in the dashboard. Here is an example from my own code;

```
  CKRecord *record = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType: @"addressRecord" ]; 
  [record setObject: patientRecord.address1 forKey: @"street1"];
  [record setObject: patientRecord.address2 forKey: @"street2"];
  [record setObject: patientRecord.city forKey: @"city"];
  [record setObject: patientRecord.state forKey: @"state"];
```

which can be inserted or modified;

```
  [privateDB saveRecord:record completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error)
  { .....
  }];
```

Your

```
  initWithRecordsToSave:myFields recordIDsToDelete:nil];
```

needs to have myFields be an array of CKRecords.

Comment: I have tried to update my code based on your suggestions but either I get an error or the saved records don't have anything in them.  In my dashboard under my container permission I created a private custom type "Pools"  and recordName "MyPoolInfo" .  I did not add any Fields.  At first I had fields of "temperature" etc.  But I don't think that is correct.  Thanks for your help but I an still doing something wrong.

Comment: post the actual error code that you get with the insert code you posted above.

Comment: this is the actual log.  Not sure how to write code to see what is going on.  ```2021-01-20 06:46:05.856774-0700 iphoneMQTT[18400:962147] this is bad
2021-01-20 06:46:05.939680-0700 iphoneMQTT[18400:962149] savedRecords:(
)```

Comment: Do you know how to use the debugger? After the saveRecord call "error" will have the reason for failure if there was one. What is the value of "error"?

Comment: getting error  ```Couldn't get container configuration from the server for container "iCloud.LLC.iphoneMQTT"```  Is the problem using default container instead of specifying the one I set up.  In my entitlements I have iCloud container Identifiers set to iCloud.XXXXXX.com.bennarts.iphoneMQTT but the iCloud Key-Value Store set to iCloud.LLC.com.iphoneMQTT.  I changed to other one but  get error: ``provisioning profile "iOS team provisioning Profile:LLC.iphoneMQTT" doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the com.apple.develper.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement.``` ???

Comment: So I got it to work.  I had to remove key-value storage as a capacity and remove that from my Capacities.  Now it is saving and modifying to the private record type.  Not sure it is the record that I set up though.  Now just to learn how to retrieve the data and put them into the UILabels.  Thanks